# Is the "NUL" character ("\0") byte separated or is it assigned to that char-array with the string?

Tags: c++, c, string, memory, null

If i define a string:

```
   char array[5] = {"hello"};
```

Is the NUL character (\0) byte "hidden" added to "array[5]", so that the array is not contained of 5 bytes in memory, it is contained of 6 bytes?

OR does the NUL character byte lie "separated" from "array[5]" in memory only after the last element of the char-array, but not directly assigned to "array[5]"?

If i would put this:

```
  i = strlen(array);
  printf("The Amount of bytes preserved for array: %d",i);
```

What would be the result for the amount of bytes preserved for array[5]?

Does the "NUL" character ("\0") byte lie separated after the last element of char-array in the memory or is it assigned to that char-array?

Comment: The null character is just another character. So your `array[5]` is one too small.

Comment: C or C++?  The effect of the code is completely different in C and C++.

Comment: @klutt see melpomene's answer. The code is valid C but invalid C++.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Does the "NUL" character ("\0") byte lie separated after the last element of char-array in the memory or is it assigned to that char-array?

No. Neither answer is correct. See below for details.

---

Answer for C:

If you write your code like that, with an explicit size that is too small for the terminator, `array` will have exactly 5 elements and there will be no NUL character.

`strlen(array)` has undefined behavior because `array` is not a string (it has no terminator). `char array[5] = {"hello"};` is equivalent to `char array[5] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};`.

On the other hand, if you write

```
char array[] = "hello";
```

it is equivalent to

```
char array[6] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

and `strlen` will report `5`.

The relevant part of the C standard is:

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally
>   enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the character string literal (**including the
>   terminating null character if there is room** or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
>   elements of the array.

(Emphasis mine.)

---

Answer for C++:

Your code is invalid. [*[dcl.init.string]*](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#string-2) states:

> There shall not be more initializers than there are array elements. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> char cv[4] = "asdf";            // error
> ```
>
> is ill-formed since there is no space for the implied trailing `'\0'`.  — *end example* ]

Comment: And in the second example, although `strlen` will report 5, `sizeof` will report 6.

Comment: @melpomene Thank you very much for your detailed answer. So i have to take care for the NUL byte to consider it as an array element? Means in opposite i couldn´t use it as a string when i would use it as i wrote before `char array[5] = "hello";` , right?

Comment: @RobertS Yes, that is correct. You could manually assign `array[4] = '\0'` and use it as a four-character string, but `char array[5] = "hello"` is not a string in the C sense.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, `char array[5] = {"hello"}` is of six bytes. But you have assigned five bytes only. Therefore, the array declaration is incorrect.

Alternatively, this works: `char array[6] = {"hello"}`.